# How can I speed up GPS fixes?

Tags: cyanogenmod, gps, motorola-defy

I'm looking for a way to speed up GPS fixes on my Motorola Defy with Cyanogenmod 7. For example today, I started up GPS Status while biking, and it got its initial fix after six minutes. What could cause my GPS to take that long for fixes and how can I speed it up?

By the way, GPS Status is configured to refresh the AGPS data every day.

Answer (score 2):

Download [Faster Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Double.FasterFix).

Simple enough, right!? =D This helped me a lot on my HTC Sensation after flashing a different European ROM. I think it also helps if you set the Language to your region, even if English *is* English. It seems to me like I don't even need this app when I set the Language to US English instead of UK English; that could just be superstition, though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that having wifi on is a major assist to Android figuring out where it is, even when it doesn't actually connect to an access point, although this may not be so helpful if you're not near any wifi access points. Also, consider for your next phone one that has a barometer (such as the Galaxy Nexus), as the barometer helps significantly with GPS acquisition by partially eliminating an axis.